# Why does Diablo stop attacking at extremely low life?

Tags: diablo-iii

I noticed that when Diablo's life gets really low (not sure the exact %, but it's below 5%) during the final stage of fighting him, he will simply stop attacking and sit there, usually in some strange "I'm dying" position

Is there a reason for this?

The only thing I've used it for so far is to res dead players before killing him, and to remove my weapons/skills and punch him (for the Punch Diablo achievement)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's just a hard-coded 'cinematic' death - my friends and I like to call it 'beating the loot pinata'. If he starts doing it, you've won - celebrate (and make inventory space for the terrible loot he's about to drop)!

Comment: when we did NM Diablo it took a long time and we were so scared to go near him thinking he just might explode and wipe us all.  ;X

Comment: Blizzard has done this before already in World of Warcraft. In the raid Icecrown Citadel where you fight the Lich King you get the last 10% of his hit points just to beat him for the sheer pleasure. Also made sense for the Lich King as many people spent a lot of time trying to beat the encounter and when you finally do you really want to enjoy those seconds where you can relief yourself of all the anger towards the boss :)

Comment: The achievement pops up when he goes into his helpless state to boot. That's your cue that you've won.