# Why can I continue to hit diablo if he is already dead?

Tags: diablo-iii

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why does Diablo stop attacking at extremely low life?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/68493/why-does-diablo-stop-attacking-at-extremely-low-life)

In Diablo 3, I can continue to hit Diablo even if the death animation has already begun.
The health bar is not yet empty (around 5% still there) when the death animation begins.

I can continue to hit until the next scene gets introduced.

Does hitting the dead body increase the drop rate or is this a bug?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe this is called a Victory Lap by Blizzard.

Comment: Have in mind that, this is the moment where you can just Unequip your weapon and main skill and earn the Punch Diablo Achievement

http://www.diablo3.org/video-guides/4464-achievement-punch-diablo.html#.T8vLIdUQtnE